# How to make navbar transparent in react native router flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I tried to transparent navbar on current page in react native router flux but i found an issue that previous navbar is gone

expected: current page not showing navbar and previous navbar stil showing when current page navbar is transparent

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try
Stack key=... hideNavBar={true}